# Yocto display Chinese/Korean/Japanese on GUI?

Tags: linux, locale, embedded-linux, yocto

I am developing a product (embedded), but it cannot display Chinese or Japanese on GUI.

I am looking at generate the image with adding zh_CN and JA_JP.utf-8 to MAGE_LINGUAS, but I have no luck. I installed chinese fonts to /usr/shared/fonts library, but it does not have the right locale. What would be the solution?

Comment: Add a tag for the programming language you are using. `c` or `c++` or ?? Note the few number of watchers for your `locale` tag. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please refer this: https://community.nxp.com/t5/QorIQ/how-to-support-chinese-in-yocto/m-p/950963#M8333

I hope it should be helpful